# How to use bash vars in statement?

Tags: bash

Really simple bash question:

In this code,

```
for i in "$@"; do
    pdftk "$i" burst output .pdfdiff_files/$i_page_%03d.pdf
done
```

How do I use the var `$i` in the statement? It's going to try to use the var `$i_page_`, so how do I separate the two?

Comment: `pdftk "$i" burst output .pdfdiff_files/${i}_page_%03d.pdf`

Comment: Thanks. just didn't know what to search

Comment: It's ok.  What matters is that the problem at hand should be resolved.